# Fatal pluggable.php wordpress error

Tags: php, wordpress

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_get_current_user() in /hermes/bosnaweb01a/b1513/ipg.framingnepalcom/wp-includes/capabilities.php on line 1329

I am getting the mentioned error in my wordpress site. I found the problem but couldn't find a permanent solution. What happens is the pluggable.php file is automatically erased from the database and ;the above error pops up disabling me to even access the admin panel. And the site gets back to normal after I upload the pluggable.php file manually. I tried downgrading wordpress, deactivating all plugins and so on. Please Help!!

Comment: So to clarify: are you saying that `pluggable.php` is being constantly being deleted?

Comment: The contents in pluggable.php gets erased automatically and the file ramains with size 0kb.

Comment: Hmm, I've never come across that error before. If you've tried disabling plugins then there's only a handful of other things I'd suggest you try: switching themes to see if that's the cause, reinstall WordPress, and check if you have cron jobs running on the server that might be deleting/modifying the file.